# How to replace a 'different' - with a 'normal' - in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using WP-property (a wordpress plugin) and am trying to use a variable as link in a template. I'm using the following code:

```
<a href="<?php echo $property['download1link']; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo   $property['download1tekst']; ?></a>
```

However, the link doesn't work as the '-' is different. How can I fix this (/replace the - with a normal -)?

Output now (ndash):

```
http://ouwejan.hostbeats.com/wp%E2%80%93content/uploads/2012/07/NVM_Goed%E2%80%93gevoel%E2%80%93NVM_Label_fc11.jpg
```

Output as it should be:

```
http://ouwejan.hostbeats.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/NVM_Goed-gevoel-NVM_Label_fc11.jpg
```

Thanks.

Comment: You mean it's not a regular hyphen, e.g. it's an ndash or mdash?

Comment: Please provide rendered sample output

Comment: What `-`? There are none in your code.

Comment: I have provided sample outputs in the main question, hope this makes it clear. The hyphen is different for some reason.

Comment: In the actual source code, the character is '&ndash;'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First go to this page:
http://slayeroffice.com/tools/ascii/
to find the ascii number of the bad "-".
You just paste your "–" in the left box on top of the page and you click the [==] button

I think it is 8211, then you do:

```
<?php echo str_replace( chr(8211) , '-' , $property['download1link'] ); ?>
```

Comment: It is 8211 indeed. However your code doesn't solve the problem, it's still 8211.

Comment: Did you try <?php echo str_replace( '&ndash;' , '-' , $property['download1link'] ); ?>

Answer (score 1):

See `str_replace()`:

http://php.net/str_replace

Example:

```
echo str_replace( 'badchar', '-', $variable );
```

Or, for more advanced replacements, `preg_replace()`:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php